# extract number of occurences of `!?` in a string

Tags: regex, string, matlab

Let's say I have this string: `S=hello !? how ?! are you ?!?! fine!?!?! thanks !?!?!? bye ?!?!?! bye !`

I would like to use regular expression to extract the number of times that `!?` occurs in a string.
In this case it should be just one.

How can I do it in Matlab?

Comment: I count 6 occurances of "!?" - you may need to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex

```
\s(!\?)\s
```

Captures the matches to !? separated by spaces. Only one in your example string. Now, how to do it in Matlab, I don't know, but it should be something like getting the matches of the regex in the string, and get the length of the returning list

Matlab code should be somethin like this:

```
str = 'hello !? how ?! are you ?!?! fine!?!?! thanks !?!?!? bye ?!?!?! bye !';
expression = '\s(!\?)\s';
matchStr = regexp(str, expression, 'match')
length(matchStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your string be defined as

```
S = 'hello !? how are you !?!? fine !?!?!?';
```

To count the number of ocurrences of `'!?`, use either of these

```
numel(regexp(S, '\!\?'))
numel(strfind(S, '!?'))
```

To count `'!?` but not `'!?!?` etc, you need to add [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in the regular expression, to make sure the sought `'!?'` is not preceded or followed by another `'!?'`:

```
numel(regexp(S, '(?<!\!\?)\!\?(?!\!\?)'))
```

Comment: I would like to avoid to count also all the other !?. It should count just one occurrence because the other !?!? are combinations of !?. The way you post captures all the occurrences of !?!

Comment: ok it could works, but as I edited the post, it takes also the one that starts as ?!?! cause it finds !? inside it. sorry about that but I need to consider all the possible cases

Comment: So you want to _not count `?!?!`...? That wasn't clear at all from your question. Which other cases do you want to not count? It's very unclear what you want

Comment: I just want to count !? and not the other multiple occurrences.

Comment: But `?!?!` is not a multiple occurrence of `!?`